# Initializing vector<string> with double curly braces

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization-list

Can someone explain the difference in behavior between initializing with double and single curly braces in the example below?

**Code #1:**

```
vector<string> v = {"a", "b"};
string c(v[0] + v[1]);
cout << "c = " << c;
cout << "c.c_str() = " << c.c_str();
```

**Output #1:**

```
c = ab
c.c_str() = ab
```

---

**Code #2:**

```
vector<string> v = {{"a", "b"}};
string c(v[0] + v[1]);
cout << "c = " << c;
cout << "c.c_str() = " << c.c_str();
```

**Output #2:**

```
c = a\acke�Z\ 
c.c_str() = a
```

Comment: I test Code#2 and throw exception on line : `vector<string> v = {{"a", "b"}};`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Implicit conversion central. That's what's going on.

1. `vector<string> v = {"a", "b"};` You initialize the vector by providing an initializer list with **two** elements. The two `std::string`s are initialized from the string literals, and then copied into the vector.
2. `vector<string> v = {{"a", "b"}};` You initialize the vector by providing an initializer with **one** element. And that single `std::string` is initialized from an initializer that has *two* elements. Accessing the second element of the vector has undefined behavior.

Now, here's the fun part. Your second snippet has undefined behavior even before you access `v[1]`. Overload resolution (to construct the single `std::string`) picks a constructor. The best viable one, is this:

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

With `InputIt` being deduced as `char const [2]` (and function parameter adjustment, turning it to `char const*`). Since those aren't really iterators, all hell breaks loose.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665914/vector-initialization-with-double-curly-braces-stdstring-vs-int Maybe you could explain the difference

Comment: Shouldn't example #2 not even compile? Why would the compiler look at {"a", "b"} and say, "Yeah, that's a string..."??

Comment: @PeterT - It doesn't say that. It says "can I make a string out of it". And sadly it can.