# Vector initialization with double curly braces: std::string vs int

Tags: c++, c++14, initializer-list, overload-resolution

In an answer to this question: [Initializing vector<string> with double curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664728/initializing-vectorstring-with-double-curly-braces#46664948)

it is shown that

```
vector<string> v = {{"a", "b"}};
```

will call the `std::vector` constructor with an `initializer_list` with **one element**. So the first (and only) element in the vector will be constructed from `{"a", "b"}`. This leads to undefined behavior, but that is beyond the point here.

What I have found is that

```
std::vector<int> v = {{2, 3}};
```

Will call `std::vector` constructor with an `initializer_list` of **two elements**.

Why is the reason for this difference in behavior?

Comment: Is it followed by a call to the vector copy constructor?

Comment: as far as I can see with the debugger, no.

Comment: Mmm.. interesting.

Comment: Okay. Took some scrutiny, but I have your answer :) Great followup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for list initialization of class types are basically: first, do overload resolution only considering `std::initializer_list` constructors and then, if necessary, do overload resolution on all the constructors (this is [[over.match.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list)).

When initializing a `std::initializer_list<E>` from an initializer list, it's as if we materialized a `const E[N]` from the *N* elements in the initializer list (from [[dcl.init.list]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#list-5)).

For `vector<string> v = {{"a", "b"}};` we first try the `initializer_list<string>` constructor, which would involve trying to initialize an array of 1 `const string`, with the one `string` initialized from `{"a", "b"}`. This is **viable** because of the iterator-pair constructor of `string`, so we end up with a vector containing one single string (which is UB because we violate the preconditions of that string constructor). This is the easy case.

---

For `vector<int> v = {{2, 3}};` we first try the `initializer_list<int>` constructor, which would involve trying to initialize an array of 1 `const int`, with the one `int` initialized from `{2, 3}`. This is **not viable**.

So then, we redo overload resolution considering all the `vector` constructors. Now, we get two viable constructors:

- `vector(vector&& )`, because when we recursively initialize the parameter there, the initializer list would be `{2, 3}` - with which we would try to initialize an array of 2 `const int`, which is viable.
- `vector(std::initializer_list<int> )`, again. This time not from the normal list-initialization world but just direct-initializing the `initializer_list` from the same `{2, 3}` initializer list, which is viable for the same reasons.

To pick which constructor, we have to go to into [[over.ics.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list), where the `vector(vector&& )` constructor is a [user-defined conversion sequence](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#7.2) but the `vector(initializer_list<int> )` constructor is [identity](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#5), so it's preferred.

---

For completeness, `vector(vector const&)` is also viable, but we'd prefer the move constructor to the copy constructor for other reasons.

Comment: I still don't understand.
`vector(vector&& )`  is just a ctor taking r-value. 
How is it related to recursion, and how does it helping answering this question?

Comment: @RioWing We're considering how to initialize a `vector<int>` from `{{2, 3}}`, and doing so involves considering how to initialize a different `vector<int>` (the move constructor parameter) from `{2, 3}`. That's recursion.

Answer (score 2):

The difference in behavior is due to default parameters. `std::vector` has this c'tor:

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, 
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Note the second argument. `{2, 3}` is deduced as `std::initializer_list<int>` (no conversion of the initializers is required) and the allocator is defaulted.

Comment: mmm.. I see it has something to do with the fact that in the first case we have `T=std::string` with argument `char [2]`, and in the second we have `T=int` with argument of the same exact type `int`, but I can't figure out why this causes the specific behaviors. Too much headache :))

Comment: @bolov - The cause is ICS ranking, and C++ being an incredibly heavy beast.