# DIfference between '{' and '(' when defining a vector<string> with integer arguments?

Tags: c++, vector

What is the difference between:

`vector<string> v1(10);` and `vector<string> v2{10};` ?

`v1.size()==v2.size()` returns 1 so are these two just the same?

Comment: Related question with more detailed but perhaps beginner-unfriendly answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46665914/8360627

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, they are the same.

Using the braced initialisation syntax (`vector<string> v2{10}`) will call the `vector<T>::vector(initializer_list<T>)` constructor if it is valid, but in this case it is not, since an `int` isn't a `std::string`, so it instead calls the `vector<T>::vector(size_type)` constructor, creating a vector with ten empty `string` elements, which is the same as what `vector<string> v1(10)`.

If you were using `vector<int>` instead of `vector<string>`, the result would be different between using braces and parentheses, with `vector<int> v1(10)` creating a vector with ten elements each equal to 0, while `vector<int> v1{10}` creates a vector with one element equal to 10.